# Issue on SLES with Veeam Backup

Tags: sles, veeam

Customer received following error when he start veeam backup:

```
Failed to execute agent management command start Backup. [...] Failed to detect bootloader on /dev/sda
```

System has been update from SLES 12 to SLES 15.
I've seen in log that this error has long been present but this time following appears in veeam Log:

```
vmb      | [SessionLog][error] BIOS boot partition size exceeds limit.
vmb      | [SessionLog][error] Failed to detect bootloader on [/dev/sda].
```

Veeam agent is running on server.

What should I check? What could be the problem?
Has anyone an Idea to resolve this issue?

Thx and best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see this statement and I think that's the problem:

> Linux veeam 6.0 are only running with veeam software 12

...and actually the veeam software is 11.